# Overloading changelist_view with no changes causing errors

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Overloading changelist_view and calling the super() causes attribute errors.

I'm creating a super basic dashboard and I am overriding the changelist_view method of a ModelAdmin class.  However, this override is resulting in an error "NoneType object has no attribute 'has_header'."  However, I'm literally not doing anything but override the changelist_view and calling the super class - I haven't made any changes yet.

In admin.py

```
class SummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        response = super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

The corresponding model in models.py

```
class Summary(Failure):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = 'Failure Summary'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Failures Summary'
```

This is literally the entire contents of the admin model.  When I try to go to the django admin panel, I get the attribute error.  As far as I can tell, this should be no different than not overriding changelist_view at all, but if I delete the override everything functions as normal.

Update:  I literally copied the changelist_view code from options.py rather than calling the super class and I do not get this error, so I suspect it has something to do with how I'm calling the super class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the above code is it lacks a return statement.  changelist_view returns a response, and an overload that does not return will cause all sorts of errors.  This is an easy mistake to make if you're used to languages that will not let you compile if you forget your return or it does not match the stated type.